# Как настроить анимацию нажатия кнопки в UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa

Имеется `UITableViewController`, в нем есть кастомная `UITableViewCell`, в которой находится `UIButton`. При клике без задержки нет эффекта `highlighted`. Вычитал, что вызвано это тем, что `UIScrollView`, на котором расположена таблица перехватывает этот клик, как поправить это не могу найти

Использовал:

```
self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

Но результата никакого нет

Comment: `delaysContentTouches` именно для этого и нужен. странно. а где вы его пишете?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko внутри `viewDidLoad` контроллера, похоже надо внутри `touchBeagn` сейчас попробую

Comment: должно работать. я, правда, никогда не пробовал это делать для таблицы. может у tableViewCell тоже есть какой то механизм задержки touch

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Подскажите пожалуйста, а как я могу достучаться до `scrollView`, на котором лежит мой `tableView`? Для того, чтобы я мог переопределить этот метод

Comment: ваш tableView унаследован от scrollView. другими словами это и есть scrollView

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Понимаю, но я не могу переопределить внутри `UITableViewController` методы `UIScrollView`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38091/discussion-between-dot-prox-and-max-mikheyenko).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C version

```
for (UIView *currentView in tableView.subviews) {
    if ([currentView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        ((UIScrollView *)currentView).delaysContentTouches = NO;
        break;
    }
}
```

Swift version

```
for currentView in tableView.subviews {
    print(currentView)
    if currentView.isKindOfClass(UIScrollView) {
      (currentView as? UIScrollView)?.delaysContentTouches = false
      break
    }
}
```