# Вложение UIScrollView в UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple

Cтолкнулся с проблемой, может кто-нибудь подскажет. Есть иерархия окна:

- page : tabview

  - back: scrollview

    - image_1 : uiimageview

      - front : scrollview

        - //content
    - image_2 : uiimageview

(схемка в прикрепленных)
В этом случае, пролема в том, что все касания пользователя принимает только "back". Как можно пробросить событие свайпа, или поставить фокус на другой, "front" scrollview?
[image: hirarchy]
<sub>(источник: [cs631528.vk.me](http://cs631528.vk.me/v631528823/225d5/b9eGCWzTFCE.jpg))</sub>

```
class randomName: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {

    let scrollViewFront = UIScrollView()
    let scrollViewBack = UIScrollView()
    var frame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    var pageIndex = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        var curY:CGFloat = 20

        let image1: UIImage = UIImage(named: «image1.png")!
        let imageView_1 = resizeImage(image1, newWidth: screenWidth-80)

        let image2: UIImage = UIImage(named: «image2.png")!
        let imageView_2 = resizeImage(image2, newWidth: screenWidth-80)

        scrollViewBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, max(imageView_1.frame.height, imageView_2.frame.height))
        scrollViewBack.center.x = screenWidth/2
        scrollViewBack.center.y = curY + 20 + scrollViewBack.frame.height/2

        scrollViewBack.addSubview(imageView_1)
        imageView_1.center.x = scrollViewBack.frame.width/2
        imageView_1.center.y = scrollViewBack.frame.height/2

        scrollViewBack.addSubview(imageView_2)
        imageView_2.center.x = scrollViewBack.frame.width + scrollViewBack.frame.width/2
        imageView_2.center.y = scrollViewBack.frame.height/2

        imageView_1.addSubview(scrollViewFront)
        scrollViewFront.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView_1.frame.width-48, imageView_1.frame.height - 42)
        scrollViewFront.center.x = imageView_1.frame.width/2   
        scrollViewFront.center.y = imageView_1.frame.height/2     

        self.view.addSubview(scrollViewBack)
        scrollViewFront.delegate = self
        scrollViewBack.delegate = self
        self.scrollViewBack.pagingEnabled = true
        self.scrollViewFront.pagingEnabled = true
        self.scrollViewBack.canCancelContentTouches = false
        self.scrollViewBack.delaysContentTouches = false
        self.scrollViewFront.canCancelContentTouches = false
        self.scrollViewFront.delaysContentTouches = false


        let first = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
        let second = UIImage(named: "2.jpg")
        let third = UIImage(named: "3.jpg")

        let images: [UIImage?] = [first,second,third]


        var count = 0
        for image in images
        {
            frame.origin.x = self.scrollViewFront.frame.size.width * CGFloat(count)
            frame.size = self.scrollViewFront.frame.size

            let subView = resizeImage((image)!, newWidth: frame.width)
            subView.frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x
            self.scrollViewFront.addSubview(subView)
            count += 1
        }
        self.scrollViewBack.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollViewBack.frame.size.width * CGFloat(2), self.scrollViewBack.frame.size.height)
        self.scrollViewFront.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollViewFront.frame.size.width * CGFloat(images.count), self.scrollViewFront.frame.size.height)

    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        pageIndex = Int(pageNumber)

    }

    func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImageView {

        let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
        let newImage = UIImageView(image: image)
        newImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width*scale, image.size.height*scale)

        return newImage
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: странно, всегда, кто может обработать touch, тот его и забирает. у вас должен только ближний скролиться. Что то там не так. посмотрите ответ на этот вопрос, может поможет. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510871/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-uitableview

Comment: если не поможет, то обрабатывайте touch руками, и, в зависимости от ситуации, либо забирайте себе, либо передавайте на superview

Comment: ну и на всякий попробуйте отключить scrolling для заднего и посмотреть начнет ли тогда передний принимать касания

Comment: @Max отключать скроллинг для заднего пробовал, тогда передний работает. но решение не подходит, потому что передний должен быть вложен в задний. свойства delaysContentTouches и canCancelContentTouches пробовал менять, тоже безрезультатно(

Comment: максимум могу предложить скинуть либо весь код, либо написать минимальный пример как это воспроизвести, чтоб можео было это дело посмотреть в действии

Comment: @Max есть еще особенность выявленная в процессе танцев с бубном. Если оба скролла добавлять как subview в главное окно - работают оба, но всеравно верхний перехватывает событие, когда идет касание именно на него, а вот то что остается за его границами - работает как и должно. Вот только этот вариант не подходит, потому что верхний нужно добавить как subview в нижний, чтобы он скроллился вместе с ним. Код скину с рабочего места

Comment: @Max добавил код. При таком раскладе скроллится только  бэк

Comment: Вы точно пробовали для заднего отключить скролиинг? У меня после этого передний скролиться не начал

Comment: @Max да, запутался, вы правы, не начинает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все вью, для которых не предполагается обработка touch (например UIImageView) по дефолту имеют `userInteractionEnabled = false`. И, соответственно, никогда не передают никакие тачи своим сабвью. Вот так получилось это все дело запустить у меня:

```
imageView_1.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: уже сам решил, спасибо большое за помощь! ответ кстати всеравно полезен, потому что сталкивался с этим и не понял почему imageView не принимает события)  буду знать на будущее)

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил сам таким образом:

1. Добавляем на основную страницу subView по размерам backScroll'a
2. Добавляем backScroll в subView.
3. Добавляем imageView_1 и imageView_2 в backScroll.
4. Добавляем frontScroll в imageView_1.
5. Добавляем контент в frontScroll.
6. Отключаем scrollEnabled у frontScroll'a и backScroll'a
7. Все события обрабатываются в subView, пишем для него tapGestureRecognizer.